# Lebesgue integral and Cantor set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need to evaluate the integral $\int_{[0,1]} f \; d\mu $ using Lebesgue integral
when $d\mu$ is Borel measurement and $f$ is given by:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}x &x\in C, \\ 
 0&x\in[0,1]\setminus C ,
\end{cases}$$
$C$ is Cantor set.

I understand that $\mu(C)=0$, so doesn't it mean that- 
 $$\int_{[0,1]} f \; d\mu =\int_{[0,1]\backslash\ C} f \; d\mu+\int_C f \; d\mu = 0+\int_C x \; d\mu$$
and $\int_C x \; d\mu =0$ because $\mu(C)=0$ ?

I think I am misunderstanding something since I also get this "clue":

if $  m\leq f(x) \leq M $, then $  \int_Am\; d\mu\leq \int_Af\; d\mu \leq \int_AM\; d\mu $.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer and your argument are correct, the integral is $\int_{[0,1]}f(x)dx=0$. I don't get the clue either... Maybe they wanted an argument like this $\forall x \in [0,1]$ it holds that $f(x) <1$.  Say that $f(x)=x <1$ only on a set of measure $0$, then run through your argument again... Although that seems quite pointless really...

Comment: Thank you. 
Apparently the clue is required in order to prove $\int_C x \; d\mu =0 $.   

I need to check why..  I thought it's clear.

Comment: Then it probably is something like the silly argument I suggested... Probably $m=0$ and $M=1$.

Comment: I think question is about  Riemann integrablity of $f$, you have to show that $m=M=0$ I guess. Otherwise, as you have shown, its lebesgue intagral is zero which is not so interesting

Comment: But I was asked explicitly to calculate the integral according to Lebesgue...

Comment: I try to do what Leo suggested:
$$0=\int_C0\; d\mu\leq \int_Cf\; d\mu \leq \int_C1\; d\mu$$
and-
 $$ \int_C1\; d\mu = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Cf_n\; d\mu $$
when- 
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}1 &x\in C, \\ 
 0&x\in[0,1]\setminus C ,
\end{cases}$$
so, 
$$ \int_C1\; d\mu = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Cf_n\; d\mu=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n \rightarrow 0  $$

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ , $V\subseteq X$ and $\mu(V)=0$ then $\int\limits_{V}f=0$.

Proof:

$$\int\limits_Vf=\int\limits_Vf^+-\int\limits_Vf^-$$
where $f^+=\max(f,0)$ and $f^-=\max(-f,0)$. According to Lebesgue integration scheme we have:

$$\int\limits_Vf^+=\lim\limits_{\Delta\to 0^{+}}\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta\mu(A_i)\tag{1}$$
where $A_i=\{x\in V:f^+(x)>i\Delta\}$.

Note that $A_i\subseteq V$ , so $0\leqslant \mu(A_i)\leqslant \mu(V)=0$ and If I am taking into account $(1)$, I'll otain $\int\limits_Vf^+=0$, this same about $f^-$ what completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're integrating a function over a set of measure $0$ and then adding to that the integral of a function whose values are all $0$ means the integral will be $0$.

So your reasoning is correct.

The hint doesn't seem to have any bearing.

Answer (score 0):

(same idea as in your answer and other answers, but using a form of the clue: not on integrals, but on null a.e property)

If $f$ null a.e. then the integral of $f$ exists and it is null. This can be shown for simple functions first. Then the simple functions dominated by $f$ must be null a.e. (this is maybe where the clue comes in), hence their integrals are null. Finally, the integral of $f$ must be null (supremum of null numbers).

(I assumed $f$ is non-negative in reasoning I presented, but it can be extended to any function by using the fact that both positive and negative parts of $f$ are dominated by $|f|$.)